# Android - Cropping after Camera and Gallery Intents Gives Strange Results

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera, android-gallery

I'm trying to launch an Android camera intent and a choose-photo intent (two buttons, one for take photo, one for choose from gallery) and both need a crop intent launched after them then have the cropped photo returned to my app's activity. I've gone through a bunch of the examples posted elsewhere, but I'm getting strange reults with my implementation.

For the take photo event, it appears to work fine, except after taking a photo and going into crop mode, the wrong photo pops up. Instead of cropping the photo you just took it crops an older photo and I can't figure out where it's coming from. Also, sometimes after finishing the crop intent, it crashes with a nullpointerexception after Parcel.readException (can't always reproduce, but I think it haappens more if you take a picture and crop as quickly as possible).

For the choose photo intent, your gallery pops up as expected but upon choosing a photo all that happens is the message "Saved" is toasted instead of returning to my app's activity with the image. I believe I have a misunderstanding of how the choose photo intent works (I pretty much reused the code for the take photo intent).

In both cases, in crop mode you are still allowed to resize the cropped area despite having specified "scale" = false.

My code is as follows:

```
public class TestPhotoActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView imageView;
private Uri imageUri;

private int int_Height_crop = 600;
private int int_Width_crop = 600;

public final static int TAKE_PICTURE = 0;
public final static int CHOOSE_PICTURE = 1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.choose_photo); 

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);

    Button take_photo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take_photo);
    take_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View view) {  
            takePhoto(view);
        }
    });

    Button choose_photo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choose_photo);
    choose_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View view) {  
            choosePhoto(view);
        }
    });     

}

public void takePhoto(View view) {      
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE", null);  
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", int_Width_crop);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", int_Height_crop);
    intent.putExtra("scale", false);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");      
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
    intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

public void choosePhoto(View view) {        
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null); 
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", int_Width_crop);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", int_Height_crop);
    intent.putExtra("scale", false);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + "Pic.jpg");        
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
    startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_PICTURE);         
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {          
        case TAKE_PICTURE:              
            Log.d("photo", "requestCode: " + requestCode + "resultCode: " + resultCode + "wanted result: " + Activity.RESULT_OK);               
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                if (data == null) {
                    Log.w("photo", "Null data, but RESULT_OK, from image picker!");
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "No photo picked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
                    return;
                }

                final Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                if (extras != null) {   
                    Log.d("photo", "extras is not null");
                    Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                    getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);                
                    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    try {
                        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);     
                        Log.d("photo", "data.getAction() is not null. setting image.");
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);                           
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("photo", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        case CHOOSE_PICTURE:
            Log.d("photo", "requestCode: " + requestCode + "resultCode: " + resultCode + "wanted result: " + Activity.RESULT_OK);
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Log.d("photo", "resultCode is ok");

                if (data == null) {
                    Log.w("photo", "Null data, but RESULT_OK, from image picker!");
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "No photo picked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
                    return;
                }

                final Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                if (extras != null) {   
                    Log.d("photo", "extras is not null");
                    Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                    getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);                
                    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    try {
                        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);  
                        Log.d("photo", "data.getAction() is not null. setting image.");
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("photo", e.toString());
                    }
                }                   

            }
    }
}

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I should also note that I'm testing on an LG Optimus LTE, Android 2.3

Comment: Same problem, in my Samsung i9000 works fine, but a lot of users of my app have strange problems with this... have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from useing System.currentTimeMillis() in the temp file name. This would explain sometimes getting an older file.

I would suggest just reusing the same temp file.

Hope it helps...